# Error response from daemon: network wikinet not found

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up HTTPS for wikijs and I am [following this article](https://docs.requarks.io/install/digitalocean).

Unfortunately, I am stuck at "docker start wiki" command as I get following error message:

> Error response from daemon: network wikinet not found
> Error: failed to start containers: wiki

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance

Comment: did you create a network `wikinet`?  Can you see it in `docker network ls`?  Maybe typo or missed command

Comment: Hi @DanielFarrell thank you for your fast reply. I haven't created wikinet, I was following the article. Can you point me in right direction regarding wikinet creation? Thank you!

Comment: Are you running this on digital-ocean?  If so you should add that to the tags

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Yes, I am running or digital ocean and I have put wikinet as tag as per your advice, however, still get the same error. Is there any other tag I should add? Thanks again